# How do I use NSFont in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried NSFont() but it says NSFont is undefined.

```
var fnt = NSFont(name: "Monaco", size: 12)
```

I have tried "import AppKit" but it says AppKit is not a valid module either.

Answer (score 13):

You're on iOS. You should be using [UIFont](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of NSFont.

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Monaco", size: 12.0)
```

You can't import [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/objc_classic/_index.html) either because it's an OS X framework. [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikit_framework/_index.html) is the framework you should be using.

Comment: ah yes, that's it, thanks for the help. Now if I could only get xcode6 to stop crashing every time the debugger pops up!

Comment: @TritonMan That's nothing, it crashed my whole system 3 times today!

Comment: wow, i get annoyed that it keeps crashing on me every time my app throws an exception or i try to debug, at least it doesn't crash my whole system...